# Find out position of node in DOM tree?

Tags: dom

I need to find out in which order two arbitrary DOM nodes appear.
Now before I start to write custom traversal code, I was wondering if there is any simple and cross browser way to find out a (comparable) location of a DOM node.

E.g.

```html
<div> <!-- pos. 1 -->
  <p> <!-- pos. 2 -->
    <span>foo</span> <!-- pos. 3 -->
    <span>bar</span> <!-- pos. 4 -->
  </p>
  <p> <!-- pos. 5 -->
    <span>foo</span> <!-- pos. 6 -->
    <span>bar</span> <!-- pos. 7 -->
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`Node.compareDocumentPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)? It returns a bitmask representing the calling node's relationship to the node passed as an argument. The reason it's a bitmask is because it may represent more than one of the possible relationships.

In this case, you can utilize `Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING` to determine the order in which two nodes appear (the result of this snippet will be in the console below the rendered page output):

```js
const foo1 = document.getElementById("foo1");
const foo2 = document.getElementById("foo2");

if (foo1.compareDocumentPosition(foo2) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING) {
  console.log("foo2 follows foo1");
} else {
  console.log("foo2 precedes foo1");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span id="foo1">foo</span>
    <span>bar</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span id="foo2">foo</span>
    <span>bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

It's widely supported, as reported by [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=comparedocumentposition):

[image]